# IE11 not restricting width with text-overflow: ellipsis

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have some HTML and CSS that shows a long string of text next to a button. The long string of text is vertically centered relative to the button, and the text shows an ellipsis `...` so it all fits inside its container.

```css
.body {
  width: 300px;
  border: thin solid black;
  height: 300px;
}

.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.content-container {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.section {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.controls {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="outer-container">
    <div class="content-container">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="section">
          abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
        </div>
      </div> <!-- end content-->
    </div> <!-- end content-container -->
    <div class="controls">
      <button>Okay</button>
    </div> <!-- end controls -->
  </div> <!-- end outer-container -->
</div> <!-- end body -->
```

This works fine in Chrome:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

But it does not work in IE11:

[image: IE11 screenshot]

Specifically, the text is not truncated, so it pushes the button off the right edge of the container. It's also not vertically centered.

[Here](https://codepen.io/KevinWorkman/pen/WNrQMxE) is a link to an editable CodePen, and [here](https://cdpn.io/KevinWorkman/debug/WNrQMxE) is the resulting page.

This is a minimal example, but in my real code, I have many repeated rows, all with text of a different (and unknown ahead of time) length, so I can't just restrict the width of the section to a hard-coded width.

Why does IE behave differently in this case, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Could you just wrap the text as a fallback using an important declaration below to overrule for other browsers that support it? Also, do you need to support IE11?

Comment: Add `width: 100%` to `.content-container`.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin Thanks for the tip. That does fix the text not being truncated, but it does not fix the vertical alignment.

Comment: Never mind, setting `height` to a `px` value fixes the vertical alignment. Thanks again.

Comment: If you want to avoid a hard-coded solution for vertical alignment, set `.content-container` to `display: flex` and move the `width: 100%` to `.content`. https://codepen.io/678789asdflu/pen/YzwygvY